# How to avoid/remove the unwanted comma in the superscript of first author like NikM^{,a}

Tags: overleaf, elsarticle, author

I am using `elsarticle` class and getting, `NikM^{,a}`. Thus the comma before `a` is unwanted. I want to remove it.

```latex
\author[1]{NikM%
\fnref{fn1}}
\ead{nik@gmail.com}

\author[2]{Ni}
\ead{nm@gmail.com}

\author[1]{Vj\corref{3}}
\cormark[3]
\ead{vid@cupaj.ac.in}

\author[2]{V. Vis}
%[orcid=]
\ead{vis@pqbox.rm}

\cortext[3]{VJ}
\fntext[fn1]{NikM}
\tnotetext[t1]{This document is the results of the research
project funded by the National Science Foundation.}

\affiliation[1]{organization={Central University of Rajasthan}, 
            city={Ajmer},
            postcode={305817}, 
            state={Rajasthan},
            country={India}
            }
\affiliation[2]{organization= {Russian Academy of Sciences},
            %addressline=, 
            city={Moscow},
            postcode= {117997}, 
           % state=,
            country={Russia}
            }
```

Comment: I changed your question for correct the [formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and change the spaghetti text into readable sentences. And only because I was already there, I changed the title to a question. But I'm not willing to speculatively extend your code fragment to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that can be used to immediately reproduce your problem. Please always try to show code, that we can use directly without the need to change or add anything.

Comment: This can be achieved by removing `\cormark[3]`.